# Why I can't select serverless capacity type when I clone Aurora Postgres DB Serverless V2 cluster?

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an Aurora Postgres DB cluster running in Serverless V2 mode. When I try to clone it I can't select Serverless capacity type because it show the `Serverless (incompatible minor version)` message:

[image: Serverless (incompatible minor version)]

Nevertheless, I can select Serverless V2 DB instance class below and specify capacity range:

[image]

Looks like the `Capacity type` field is related to Serverless V1 only and I can ignore it when I'm cloning Serverless V2 cluster.

And looks like the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html) point to this too:

> You can choose Serverless only if the source Aurora DB cluster is an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster or is a provisioned Aurora DB cluster that is encrypted.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the serverless engine mode refers to Serverless v1. The reason why it forces you to select provisioned is because provisioned and Serverless v2 clusters are interchangeable [1]; you can have v2 instances in a provisioned cluster.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.create-cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

Correct. I think the labelling is a little confusing in the console because "capacity type" is referring to the cluster as a whole, while "instance type" is what sets the capacity of the instance. Where with Serverless v2, the capacity of the instance varies. While with Serverless v1, the serverless aspect applies to the whole cluster.

Most of the references to Serverless v1 in the console aren't shown when you're on a version that's higher than v1 supports. It's possible the presence of the radio button is just an oversight. Which engine version are you running on the cluster that you're cloning?